# Upper bound of the difference between two weighted sum

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

For $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X_i, Y_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$,

Is there any upper bound of the difference between two weighted sums, which looks like below?

$ \sum_i a_i X_i - \sum_i a_i Y_i  <= |\sum_i X_i - \sum_i Y_i| * const $

the const may be any real number related to $a, X, Y$.

I tried $a_{max}$ but I think that is wrong.

if there is no, how about when $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the expression inside the absolute values can be zero even when the left-hand side is nonzero, the answer is no, there is no such inequality.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you!